Нужна помощь с TS и Record
нужно сделать Record, где ключи типа key_1, key_2, ... (много), и значение типа number. Как сделать ключи?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

type T = Record<`key_${number}`, number>;

